# get the max of R,G,B of one image by using programming

Tags: java, php, python, c

in photoshop, normally I need to adjust by hand to set the maximum value of R,G or B.

[image]

is there any image library (python,java,C#.) to get ,to calculate or to set the maximum of R,G,and B?

I have a look at PIL (python image library) but not found the point.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To *get* the maximum** red, green, blue value you can use the Python library SciPy:

```py
from scipy import misc

img = misc.imread("lena.bmp")

print "R:", img[:, :, 0].max()
print "G:", img[:, :, 1].max()
print "B:", img[:, :, 2].max()
```

Output:

```
R: 255
G: 238
B: 255
```

---

**To *set* the maximum** value of a certain color channel you can multiply all pixels with a scale factor, e.g.

```
factor = 240.0 / img[:, :, 0].max()
img[:, :, 0] *= factor
print "new R:", img[:, :, 0].max()
```

Output:

```
new R: 240
```

---

Just in case you need to **set both, minimum and maximum**:

```
newMinR = 50.0
newMaxR = 240.0

factor = (newMaxR - newMinR) / (img[:, :, 0].max() - img[:, :, 0].min())
shift = newMinR - factor * img[:, :, 0].min()

img[:, :, 0] = factor * img[:, :, 0].astype('float') + shift
print "new R:", img[:, :, 0].min(), img[:, :, 0].max()
```

Output:

```
new R: 50 240
```

(The formula for computing the `factor` and `shift` can be derived from a linear function like `newR = factor * oldR + shift`. Make sure to use floats rather than `uint8`!)

Comment: That is want I want. Thanks so much Falko

Comment: for all image has .jpg is that true? that I always get R: 255
G: 255
B: 255

Comment: @kn3l: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checkrgb.py", line 5, in <modul
    print "R:", img[:, :, 0].max()
IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: @kn3l: Looks like your image has one gray channel only. So the index ```0``` is wrong. You can still get the maximum gray value ```img[:, :].max()``` or simply ```img.max()```.